# How can I make this find command work recursively in the current directory?

Tags: unix, directory, find

I have this `find` command and need to make it work recursively in the current directory  ( at the moment it searches all the files on the disk )

```
find . -name ‘OldName*’ -print0 | xargs -0 rename -S ‘OldName’ ‘NewName’
```

Any idea how to make it search in the current directory that I am navigated to in terminal ?

Comment: `find .` means search recursively current directory only... and you don't need xargs, just use -exec... see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/313819/add-file-extension-to-files-that-have-no-extension

Comment: Ahh I didnt realise that thanks Sundeep :)

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
find . -name 'OldName' -exec rename -n 'OldName' 'NewName' \;
```